# Mongo query displaying weekday field

Tags: mongodb, metabase

I'm trying to figure out how I can add the name of the weekday to the fields that are shown? So far it works, but it only shows the fields "Count" and "Completed At".

It should display the following:

```
| Weekday | Count |
–––––––––––––––––––
| Monday  |   1   |
| Tuesday |   10  |
| Wedne.. |  ...  |
```

Here is my query:

```
 [
      {
        "$project": {
          "completedAt": "$completedAt",
          "status": "$status"
        }
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "$and": [
            {
              "status": {
                "$eq": "successful"
              }
            },
            {
              "completedAt": {
                "$gt": ISODate("2019-01-01")
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": "$_id",
          "___group": {
            "completedAt": {
              "$dayOfWeek": "$completedAt"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$___group",
          "count": {
            "$sum": 1
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "_id": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": false,
          "completedAt": "$_id.completedAt",
          "count": true
        }
      },
      {
        "$sort": {
          "completedAt": 1
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: You should maintain this at the front end. `$dayOfWeek` `Returns the day of the week for a date as a number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday).`

Comment: Is there any way to turn the number into the respective weekday?

Comment: You have to create an array with key value pair from 1 to 7 with value of week day as string. `[
  { _id: 1, day: 'Sun' }, { _id: 2, day: 'Mon' },
  { _id: 3, day: 'Tue' }, { _id: 4, day: 'Wed' },
  { _id: 5, day: 'Thu' }, { _id: 6, day: 'Fri' },
  { _id: 7, day: 'Sat' }
]
` . This should be done after aggregation. Probably when you are showing this on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the labels including the $switch to the query solved it for me.

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "completedAt": "$completedAt",
      "status": "$status"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "status": {
            "$eq": "successful"
          }
        },
        {
          "completedAt": {
            "$gt": ISODate("2019-01-01")
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "___group": {
        "completedAt": {
          "$dayOfWeek": "$completedAt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$___group",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": false,
      "count": true,
      "label": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 1] },
              "then": "Sunday"
            },
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 2] },
              "then": "Monday"
            },
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 3] },
              "then": "Tuesday"
            },
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 4] },
              "then": "Wednesday"
            },
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 5] },
              "then": "Thursday"
            },
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 6] },
              "then": "Friday"
            },
            {
              "case": { "$eq": ["$_id.completedAt", 7] },
              "then": "Saturday"
            }
          ],
          "default": "Unknown"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "completedAt": 1
    }
  }
]
```